# JEditorPane counterpart in javafx

Tags: javafx

is there a JEditorPane counterpart in javafx?
I cant just add a normal JEditorPane to a Pane, but I need one, so is there a way to have one in javafx?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/editor.htm

Answer (score 0):

There's not a JEditorPane equivalent in Java FX for now. I've made a request to JIRA about it, and I hope they are going to implement this component soon.

But, from Java FX 8.0, you are able to add a Swing Component in a Java Fx control by the mean of SwingNode.

[This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm) explains how to do that.

I've personnaly tested it. It works quite well, but it's not the solution I will recommand because it generates some bugs due to thread problems.

Use it like a placeholder but it's not the best solution.

Otherwise, you can deal with HTMLEditor or WebView to manage web content.